# Add 'Display Name' in discussion list

Tags: user-profile, user-profile-property, discussion-board

Is there any way I can use the 'Display name' or some other user profile property in the view of a discussion list?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirement correctly, you want to see a column with the user's name. In that case, it should already show what you want with the "Created By" column, which is already on the default view of a Discussion Board.

[image]

Comment: Thanks- unfortunately, that's what I'm trying to avoid.  I would like the users to be able to choose a name that would be used exclusively for the discussion board.  For some it might be their actual name, but for the more privacy-conscious, it could be 'cowboy72' or a more vague handle of their choosing.